# Improving the video quality

Tags: video, video-capture

I recorded a video- from VHS to my computer, but the quality of the recorded video is worse than the original one (if I plug the VHS directly to the TV comparimg to the recording to my computer).

My question is if someone knows about program that improves the quality of the recorded video?
I know it will not be an HD quality, but it will be great to make the best of it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing Called SISO rule in video editing (Shit In Shit Out) sorry for the language, that's the real name of it, clearly it just means video enhancing is able to do some help but no real Hollywood FBI enhancement. you need to fix the source problem.

Depending on the quality loss type you could check these things:

If there is much noise added: probably an issue with the cables check they are no lossy parts and of a 'good enough' quality

If the image is pixelated, it's clearly a encoder setting issue, VHS, if you're ine Europe, use 720x576 with 25 images per sec, if you're US, use 640x480 with 30i/s (depending on your vhs reader)

If it is another issue, just explain. How are you encoding the videos on your computer?

Comment: I use 720x576 and 25 images per sec.
the thing is that I record it to my computer thought "easycap" and it demmages the quality- it is not pixelated, more noisy or hazy..

Comment: If its analog quality loss, then it's clearly before the encoder app, if it's digital quality loss, like poor youtube videos, then it's the app. Hope i'm clear?

Comment: it is digital quality loss. the "easycap" damages the quality- programly. I am looking for program to improve the quality..